# How to backup MySQL Database laravel 4.2 with cronjob

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4.2

I have an project laravel 4.2 and now I will automatically make weekly backup of the database.
I find script but its not working

```
    public function fire()
    {
        try {
            $this->process = new Process(sprintf(
                'mysqldump -u%s -p%s %s > %s',
                config('database.connections.mysql.username'),
                config('database.connections.mysql.password'),
                config('database.connections.mysql.database'),
                storage_path('backups/backup.sql')
            ));

            $this->info('The backup has been proceed successfully.');
        } catch (ProcessFailedException $exception) {
            $this->error('The backup process has been failed.');
        }
    }

    protected function getArguments()
    {
        return array();
    }
```

Showing error

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function config() in /var/www/html/guitarni_portal/app/commands/BackupDatabase.php on line 25
>   Error in exception handler: The stream or file "/var/www/html/guitarni_portal/app/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/guitarni_portal/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using too old laravel. But still, you can use,

`Config::get` instead of `config`.

Should work.

Comment: Yes its working but file not saved,

I change permission 777 of storage  but not working

Comment: own that file and then change permission, check if its working. But that's not related to this question.